# How to find DELETE and UPDATE statements that have been executed on a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, audit

I am trying to find out what delete and update statements have been executed on a certain database in a certain period of time.

I came across this following query, but it generates an error message:

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
where dest.TEXT like '%Delete%from%'
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

The error message is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '.'.

If I try:

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS dest
where dest.TEXT like '%Delete%from%'
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

I get another error:

```
Msg 321, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
"sql_handle" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.
```

As far as I understand in my research of the topic it is not an easy task to achieve.

Is this query even the right approach?

SQL VERSION in question:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit)
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      10.0.2531.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        10.0.1600.22
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7600.16385
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     8.0.7600.16385
Microsoft .NET Framework                        2.0.50727.4984
Operating System                        6.1.7600
```

Comment: This SQL query is required to execute on [Master] database.

Comment: @wachy - No it isn't but it requires to be run under a DB with the correct compatibility level. Changing the compatibility level of the user database to SQL Server 2008 would also work.

Comment: looks like if you run it against the master DB it works. tnx Wachy

Comment: This assumes the OP is actually on 2008. The version shown in the question is version of SSMS not server version.

Comment: IT is MS sql Server 2008

Comment: I go it working now but I have query's with parameters @P1,@P2,... any way to see the values of that?

Comment: @Jester - No. The query just returns the plans that happen to be in the cache. If they were parameterised the actual run time values the plans were executed with or not stored anywhere. The best you can do is find the parameter values the plans were compiled with by looking in the XML for the plan (and you can get the XML by adding `query_plan` to the `SELECT` and `CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(deqs.plan_handle) AS Q` before the `WHERE`

Comment: Mybe possable to see what machine the statment cam from? since all users executing on that database have the same credentials :S

Comment: @Jester - No the machine name information is not stored. If you need this you need to set up some kind of auditing in advance it is not generally possible to get this retrospectively.

Comment: Any Idea where to see the user? I think they should be all the same but just to rule out it came from the same app.

Answer (score 8):

Run this in the context of the `master` database as you must be running it under the context of a user database set to SQL Server 2000 compatibility level.

The following should work fine

```
USE master;

SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time],
       dest.TEXT                AS [Query]
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE  dest.text LIKE '%Delete%from%'
ORDER  BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, you query works. I have SQL Server 2008 R2. The second one is also launchable

[image]

Comment: I have SQL Server 2008 NOT R2 and I get the above error

Comment: Will try to restore the DB on the R2 server and see what happens

Comment: And what is you version (Standart, Developer, Enterprise)?

Comment: Version info Added above

Comment: I suppose, that the problem might be in version. I've changed the copability to 80, 90 and 100 - it worked. And USE master - is not nesessary, it works without it